# Selenium WebDriver-Chrome

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Hi all i am using `selenium backed webdriver` i am automating some third party site so i don't have any access to the code of that site problem is that my selenium test case `works well firefox` but when i `use chromedriver it gives an exception` Element is not clickable at point (693, 14). Other element would receive the click i read on some blog that using the lines of code makes the problem go the lines are given below

```
 WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
 WebElement element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='sendFile']")));
 element.click();
```

But still face same issue.
Someone please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Try with `JavascriptExecutor` as below:-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); 
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='sendFile']")));     
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Hope it will work...:)